# SvgImageSource not loading in custom element using ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, svg, uwp

I am currently porting my WinUI3 library to UWP and I have some issues with loading SVG data as an image.

I have made a custom element like this: `public sealed class CustomButton : Button`. Inside this custom button I have a property called `Icon` with the type `imageSource`.

My UI is created with a ResourceDictionary and is imported in the MergedDictionaries in App.xaml like this: `<CustomDictionary xmlns="using:CustomLibrary.UWP.UI" />`.
My default template looks like this:

```xml
...
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomButton">
      <Grid x:Name="RootLayout">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image
          Width="19"
          Height="19"
          Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}" />
        <TextBlock
          Name="ContentElement"
          Grid.Column="2"
          Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
...
```

Now my issue: I want to set different icons (SVG data) for different custom button styles but the library user should also be able to set custom images for the button style. For example for the "DefaultCustomButtonStyle" I have the "Icon.Default" and for "SecondaryCustomButtonStyle" I have "Icon.Second".

In WinUI3 I converted SVG data to `SvgImageSource` inside the code-behind of the ResourceDictionary like this: `((Style)this["DefaultCustomButtonStyle"]).Setters.Add(new Setter(CustomButton.IconProperty, Icons.ToImageSource(Icons.Default)));`. Of course I wanted to just set the Icon Setter directly in the Style but you cant use x:Bind in ResourceDictionaries.

Anyways when trying to this in UWP the image is just blank. While debugging I noticed that the image gets created and also has the correct size but its just empty.

The `Icons.ToImageSource` function works correctly and is tested. For example If I just set the source of an Image to this it displays it correctly. This is the code btw:

```cs
public static ImageSource ToImageSource(
  string svg,
  int width,
  int height)
{
  using MemoryStream stream = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(svg));
  stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

  SvgImageSource imageSource = new()
  {
    RasterizePixelWidth = width,
    RasterizePixelHeight = height,
  };
  imageSource.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream()).AsTask();
  return imageSource;
}
```

Also something interesting which may be usefull: As I said the user imports the ResourceDictionary in the MergedDictionaries inside App.xaml like this: `<CustomDictionary xmlns="using:CustomLibrary.UWP.UI" />`. When doing this in App.xaml it has this weird bug. But when importing it inside the view which uses the `CustomButton` everything works fine.

I have created a sample project: https://github.com/IcySnex/SvgSample

Comment: Could you please create a native UWP project and reproduce this behavior in it? If you could, please share the native UWP repro.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Sorry that it took me so long, I havent worked on my project in a while. But I have created a small sample project and uploaded it to GitHub: https://github.com/IcySnex/SvgSample

Comment: @IcySnex GitHub returns 404

Comment: @YevhenCherkes Oops my bad. Fixed it

Comment: I can't run the sample downloaded from the GitHub. Could you please check it again?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Hello, could give me a little bit more information on why it is not running? Is there some error or what happens?

Comment: Missing `AssemblyInfo.cs` and `SvgSampleLibrary.dll` in the properties of the SvgSampleLibrary project. I'm testing on a new VM. Can you run your sample on a new device?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I have added the AssemblyInfo for both projects. It should be compiling now.

Comment: I made some test about the `SvgImageSource`, Using other image as source like a png image and `bitmapimage`. All the functions are working as expected.  The issue only happens to the `SvgImageSource`. Not sure if this is related to the look up order of the resource dictionary as well. Does it work when using an existing SVG file instead of the string?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I also came to the conclusing that loading BitmapImages from an online source works fine. I have updated the sample project so you can switch between loading a svg from memory and from a resource file. Loading a resource file works fine but I want to avoid shipping any resources in my control library, this is why I want to store all of my svgs in memory.